# relational record で auto increment なカラムの値を指定せずに insert する方法

Tags: haskell

relational record で auto increment なカラムの値を指定せずに insert する方法を教えてください。また、そのときに auto increment されて insert された値も取得したいです。

1日ほどソースコードの [`Database.Relational.Query.SQL.insertPrefixSQL`](https://github.com/khibino/haskell-relational-record/blob/64ddb508475363d735c60d85441e686482feeadd/relational-query/src/Database/Relational/Query/SQL.hs#L95-L98) の中身を読んでみたのですが、`Projection` と `Pi` の役割が理解できず insert するカラムを指定する方法がよく分かりませんでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

relational-recordの仕組みについて十分に理解していないのでスマートな方法ではないかもしれませんが、要望の処理は満たせましたので回答します。

relational-recordのdefineTable*で生成される型はテーブルのすべてのカラムを含むので、
auto incrementやdefaultが指定されているカラムの値を指定せずにINSERTしたいときは、
自分でカラムを減らした型を定義する必要があります。

生成される型と作った型の対応を表現するのに`Pi`が必要です。
(`Projection`との違いは、`Projection`がSQL型-Haskell型の対応を表すのに対して`Pi`はHaskell型-Haskell型の対応を表す点でないかと思います)。
元の型`A`から別の型`B`への対応は`Pi A B`と表現します。
`Pi A B`はApplicativeの`<$>, <*>`によく似た`|$|, |*|`を使うと楽に作れます。

**TestTable.hs**

```
module TestTable where

import qualified Data.Text as T

import DataSource (defineTable)

import Database.Relational.Query hiding (id')
import Database.HDBC.Query.TH (makeRecordPersistableDefault)

-- create table test_table (
--   id integer primary key auto_increment,
--   name varchar(40) not null
--   );
$(defineTable "test_table")

data TestTable1 = TestTable1 { t1Name :: T.Text }
$(makeRecordPersistableDefault ''TestTable1)

piTestTable1 :: Pi TestTable TestTable1
piTestTable1 = TestTable1 |$| name'
-- `name'`はdefineTableで生成される

insertAutoIncrement :: Insert TestTable1
insertAutoIncrement = typedInsert tableOfTestTable piTestTable1
-- `tableOfTestTable`はdefineTableで生成される
```

またMySQLのauto incrementで生成された値は[MySQLのC APIもしくはSQL関数](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/example-auto-increment.html)で取得できます。
relational-record上でそのSQL関数を使うには以下のようにすればいいでしょう。
(C APIをrelational-recordやHDBCで使う方法は分かりませんでした)。

**MySQLFunction.hs**

```
module MySQLFunction where

import Data.Int (Int64)

import Database.Relational.Query
import Database.Relational.Query.Type (unsafeTypedQuery)

selectLastInsertId :: Query () Int64
selectLastInsertId = unsafeTypedQuery "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()"
```

以上をまとめると以下のように使えます。

**Main.hs**

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad (forM)

import DataSource (connect)
import TestTable
import MySQLFunction

import Database.HDBC (withTransaction)
import Database.HDBC.Record (runQuery, prepareInsert, runPreparedInsert)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    conn <- connect
    withTransaction conn $ \conn' -> do
        prepared <- prepareInsert conn' insertAutoIncrement
        forM ["Simon", "Robin", "Douglas"] $ \nm -> do
            _ <- runPreparedInsert prepared $ TestTable1 nm
            lastId <- runQuery conn' selectLastInsertId ()
            print lastId
    return ()

-- > [1]
-- > [2]
-- > [3]
```